# Laravel Prevent Form from Re submitting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I have a form of Adding Album in database

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['admin.album.store'], 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'id' => 'CreateAlbumForm']) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

// other fields

{!! Form::submit(trans('global.app_save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

It is working perfectly.

What i need is to prevent user from clicking submit button multiple times. which i know is possible with **jquery ( disabling submit button on click)**.

But i want to make it using **`csrf` protection(Server side) when user does not have javascript enabled**.

After a lot of search i found below solution :

**What i have tried**

Adding Below function in `VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (!$token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }

    $tokensMatch = ($request->session()->token() == $token) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if($tokensMatch) $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return $tokensMatch;
}
```

And adding `_token` inside `$dontFlash` array in file `app\Http\Requests\FormRequest.php`

```
protected $dontFlash = ['password', 'password_confirmation', '_token'];
```

It gives me Token Mismatch error But when i click on submit button more than 2 times. And record is inserted 2 times which is unwanted behaviour.

It should give me error on 2nd attempt on submit at same time.

So in short What i need is if a user clicks on submit button single time it should insert record. and if he clicks on submit more than one time than it should give TokenMismatch Error.

Comment: Why don't you add an onclick method to disable the form when its submitted then use validation on the form to prevent it being inserted in the database? 

Using unique on the album data fro example 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: @rchatburn  I want to do it server side. I used `unique` so as expected behaviour it will return error message as `this is already added` but i dont want to show that error message i just want to add single record and redirect user to the list.

Answer (score 1):

`You could set a token when you serve the form and check that against the database. When you submit the form, the token is checked and you can't submit it any more. Of course, it is still a good idea to do it front-end too as it is more visual for the user.`

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/stopping-multiple-form-submission

Just searching for relevant answer and found this. Hope it will help in some way.

Comment: I think there will be some configuration in csrf token protection only. As I am passing csrf token in hidden field. And that is also working but still it allows for 2 time clicking. I don't know how. It should not allow second request